# Pandas - multiple new columns based on cumprod and condition in other column

Tags: python, pandas, method-chaining

I have a dataframe `df` with two columns, `df["Period"]` and `df["Return"]`. `df["Period"]` has number from 1, 2, 3, ... n and is increasing. I want to calculate new columns using `.cumprod` of `df["Return"]` where `df["Period"]` >= 1, 2, 3 etc. Note that the number of rows for each unique period is different and not systematic.

So I get `n` new columns

- `df["M_1]`: is cumprod of df["Return"] for rows `df["Period"]` >= 1
- `df["M_2]`: is cumprod of df["Return"] for rows `df["Period"]` >= 2
- ...

Below my example which is working. The implementation has two drawbacks:

1. it is very slow for large number of unique periods
2. it does not work well with pandas method chaining

**Any hint of how to speed this up and/or to vectorize this is appreciated**

```
import numpy as np 
import pandas as pd

# Create sample data
n = 10
data = {"Period": np.sort(np.random.randint(1,5,n)),
        "Returns": np.random.randn(n)/100, }
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# Slow implementation
periods = set(df["Period"])
for period in periods:
    cumret = (1 + df.query("Period >= @period")["Returns"]).cumprod() - 1
    df[f"M_{month}"] = cumret
df.head()
```

This is the expected output:

|  | Period | Returns | M_1 | M_2 | M_3 | M_4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 | -0.0268917 | -0.0268917 | nan | nan | nan |
| 1 | 1 | 0.018205 | -0.00917625 | nan | nan | nan |
| 2 | 2 | 0.00505662 | -0.00416604 | 0.00505662 | nan | nan |
| 3 | 2 | -8.28544e-05 | -0.00424855 | 0.00497334 | nan | nan |
| 4 | 2 | 0.00127519 | -0.00297878 | 0.00625488 | nan | nan |
| 5 | 3 | -0.00224315 | -0.00521524 | 0.0039977 | -0.00224315 | nan |
| 6 | 3 | -0.0197291 | -0.0248414 | -0.0158103 | -0.021928 | nan |
| 7 | 3 | 0.00136592 | -0.0235094 | -0.0144659 | -0.020592 | nan |
| 8 | 4 | 0.00582897 | -0.0178175 | -0.00872129 | -0.0148831 | 0.00582897 |
| 9 | 4 | 0.00260425 | -0.0152597 | -0.00613975 | -0.0123176 | 0.0084484 |

Comment: are the values in the desired output correct ? how do you calculate the value of index 1 column `M_1` ? shouldn't that be "-0.0268917 * 0.018205" which is different from your result ("-0.00917625)

Comment: Yes, it is (1 -0.0268917) * (1 + 0.018205) - 1 = -0.0091762633984999

Answer (score 1):

Here is how your code performs on my machine (Python 3.10.7, Pandas 1.4.3) in average after 10,000 iterations:

```py
import statistics
import time

import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

elapsed_time = []
for _ in range(10_000):
    start_time = time.time()

    periods = set(df["Period"])
    for period in periods:
        cumret = (1 + df.query("Period >= @period")["Returns"]).cumprod() - 1
        df[f"M_{period}"] = cumret

    elapsed_time.append(time.time() - start_time)

print(f"--- {round(statistics.mean(elapsed_time), 6):2} seconds in average ---")
print(df)
```

Output:

```py
--- 0.00298 seconds in average ---

   Period   Returns       M_1       M_2       M_4
0       1 -0.008427 -0.008427       NaN       NaN
1       1  0.019699  0.011106       NaN       NaN
2       2  0.012661  0.023908  0.012661       NaN
3       2 -0.005059  0.018728  0.007538       NaN
4       4  0.025452  0.044657  0.033182  0.025452
5       4  0.010808  0.055948  0.044349  0.036535
6       4  0.004843  0.061062  0.049407  0.041555
7       4  0.005791  0.067207  0.055484  0.047587
8       4 -0.001816  0.065269  0.053568  0.045685
9       4  0.014102  0.080291  0.068425  0.060431
```

With some minor modifications, you can get a **~3x speed improvement**:

```py
elapsed_time = []
for _ in range(10_000):
    start_time = time.time()

    for period in df["Period"].unique():
        df[f"M_{period}"] = (
            1 + df.loc[df["Period"].ge(period), "Returns"]
        ).cumprod() - 1

    elapsed_time.append(time.time() - start_time)

print(f"--- {round(statistics.mean(elapsed_time), 6):2} seconds in average ---")
print(df)
```

Output:

```py
--- 0.001052 seconds in average ---

   Period   Returns       M_1       M_2       M_4
0       1 -0.008427 -0.008427       NaN       NaN
1       1  0.019699  0.011106       NaN       NaN
2       2  0.012661  0.023908  0.012661       NaN
3       2 -0.005059  0.018728  0.007538       NaN
4       4  0.025452  0.044657  0.033182  0.025452
5       4  0.010808  0.055948  0.044349  0.036535
6       4  0.004843  0.061062  0.049407  0.041555
7       4  0.005791  0.067207  0.055484  0.047587
8       4 -0.001816  0.065269  0.053568  0.045685
9       4  0.014102  0.080291  0.068425  0.060431
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Learnt something. Although I am surprised that `.query` is so much slower.